# Change behaviour of numpad to dpad in GNOME 3

Tags: gnome3, keyboard-layout

I'm a long-time Windows user who uses the numeric keypad with the numlock off for navigating text, highlighting it, etc. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> (<kbd>7</kbd> on the numpad) selects all text till the beginning of the line. In GNOME, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> on the numpad inputs `7` instead of selecting all text till the beginning of the line.

Is there a way to change the behaviour of the numpad in GNOME 3 to that of the direction pad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an option for it in the typing settings: open `gnome-tweak-tool` and in the *Typing* section expand *Miscellaneous compatibility options* and check the option *"NumLock on: digits, Shift switches to arrow keys, NumLock off: always arrow keys (as in MS Windows)"*
Or you could use `dconf-editor`, navigate to *org>gnome>desktop>input-sources>xkb-options* and add `'numpad:microsoft'` to the existing values.

For a desktop-agnostic solution, you can use `setxkbmap -option numpad:microsoft` in your X startup files.