# Relationship between setxkbmap and xorg.conf

Tags: x11, xorg, gnome3, keyboard-layout

I wish to adjust my shift+numpad-home behavior microsoft-like. At my previous distros, I remember appending in my `xorg.conf.d/*keyboard.conf` an XkbOption and that solved it all. Now I took the same path to no avail, and after some more research, I had to do `setxkbmap -option numpad:microsoft`to solve my problem. Apperantly, my `xorg.conf` files get either overwritten or ignored at each system startup. To be more precise, my added line did not get overwritten, but ignored. Then when I renamed `00-keyboard.conf` as `80-keyboard.conf` to see how it behaves, it created a default `00-keyboard.conf` file from scratch on startup.

What is the exact relationship between `setxkbmap` and `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` configs? Where does whatever store its default configs which overwrite my own configs? Is it just another intrusive systemd way of doing things, or is it me being paranoid, as I have a strong dislike of systemd?

To clarify, I did manage to get the result I want, I'm just trying to see what's under the hood.

**Summary:** What is the mechanism that ignores my manual changes in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/*-keyboard.conf` and forces me to use `setxkbmap` instead? Where are the defaults stored, and how and why does it overwrite at each startup?

Comment: Nah, it's regular Gnome with X11.

Comment: Related background questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22092/ and https://askubuntu.com/questions/57079/ .

Comment: systemd was my first guess, if it's irrelevant, I modified my tags.

Comment: @JdeBP First one merely tells the solution, second link points to `/etc/default/keyboard`, I'll experiment with that directory a bit.

Comment: `setxkbmap` uses the keyboard extension on the running server, `xorg.conf` gets read at startup of the server. Otherwise they should be the same. To find out why your `xorg.conf` settings are ignored, the first step is to look at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation for the behavior you describe is:

- The settings in `xorg.conf` work.
- When you log in, your desktop environment changes the configuration from the *system* defaults to your *user* defaults, which is a perfectly reasonable thing to do.
- If you run `setxkbmap` later, that changes the configuration of the current session.

You need to either figure out how to configure your desktop environment for the behavior you want, or to run that `setxkbmap` command as part of something that runs late enough during your desktop environment's initialization process.